# NSUndoManager not calling selected method in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview, nsundomanager

OK, so I have an app with a UITextView that I want to exhibit standard Undo behaviour. I have trawled lots of tutorials and answers on this site as well as the Apple Developer Docs and I can't understand why what I have produced is not working.

Whenever the UITextView is modified (I am using a non-standard keyboard using the textView.inputView property) the method below is passed a string that is the new text required for the text view:

```
- (void)setText:(NSString*)text{

NSString *oldText = [textView.text mutableCopy];

if (text != oldText) {

    [undoManager registerUndoWithTarget:self selector:@selector(setText:) object:oldText];  
    textView.text = text;

    }
}
```

and then to implement the undo when a UIButton is pressed

```
[undoManager undo];
```

is executed.

I have declared undoManager in my header file using

```
NSUndoManager *undoManager;
```

and synthesised it in my implementation but when I press the undo UIButton nothing happens and setText is never called. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the *initialisation* of the undoManager is still missing in your example. You declare

```
NSUndoManager *undoManager;
```

in you headerfile, but I do not see where you allocate/initialize it.

Try adding

```
undoManger = [NSUndoManager alloc] init];
```

in you i.e. "viewDidLoad" (or similar) method. Do not forget to release the object appropriate, when you don't need it anymore, for example in dealloc.

Comment: You could also get the default NSUndoManager from the UIWindow: every UIView is a UIResponder, which has a standard read-only undoManager property. Ask for it (eg. `self.undoManager`), and it will go up the responder chain until it finds one (by default, the window will return one). That's what documentation will tell you, anyway. I find that a UIViewController subclass in the chain will break this, though. In order get around that, you could override its undoManager method to `return self.nextResponder.undoManager`.